# Creating A Pop Up Outside Of App Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an app that needs to create a pop up to notify the user of something, even when the app is closed. I would like it to be fullscreen, but if that's not possible, a pop up that takes up most of the screen will do. I don't know how to make part of the app run in the background on Android and iOS to check if it's time for the pop up. I also don't know how to go about making the actual pop up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Side notes: I am using a cross platform Xamarin.Forms app. I have a main page that the user can set the time they want the pop up to appear, and I save this to the Application.Current.Properties dictionary for data persistence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background tasks on mobile has quite a lot of limitations. Which is logical. The user would not like if some app will always run in background and collect user data, drain the battery or affect overal performance of the the mobile device. Therefore for there are strict set of rules every developer must follow when creating a background tasks.

You best bet would be to use local notifications, there is a well documented [open source library](https://github.com/edsnider/localnotificationsplugin) that you can use for this. There will be no pop-ups but notifications which you could customize according to OS guides.